# Shouldn't the favorite button tooltip change based on whether it has been clicked or not?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks, tooltips

The tooltip for the favorite star states:

*This is a favorite question (click again to undo)*

regardless of whether you have favorited the question or not.

Shouldn't it say something like *'Click to favorite'* when you haven't yet favorited the question, and then *'This is a favorite question (click again to undo)'* when you have favorited it?

Comment: I would say "because upvote and downvote have that as well", but it's only upvote that has the "(click again to undo)". Downvote does not when it's not activate (and sorry for playing with the votes on your post).

Comment: @gunr2171 For me both the upvote and downvote arrows add "(click again to undo)" to their tooltips when you've actually performed that action already, but it's not there when you haven't.

Comment: Should this be on http://meta.stackexchange.com/ rather than here?  It seems to apply to all sites.

Comment: @DonRoby, it is already on [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143350), with status 'declined'.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Analysis on consistency

When unclicked, the vote buttons describe the conditions under which you would want to click them, for example:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear

After clicking them, the text is expanded to:

> This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear (click again to undo)

---

To stay consistent in this way, the favorite button should contain the condition under which you would want to click it:

> This is a favorite question

And should be expanded when you have already clicked it:

> This is a favorite question (click again to undo)

---

## Conclusion

The tooltip is indeed not consistent. However, it should not be changed into describing the corresponding action (like you suggest), but simply the last part should get cut off as long as it is unclicked.